# Android measure FPS

Tags: android, performance, logcat, frame-rate, dumpsys

To evaluate the performance and "buttery smootheness" of my developed Android App, i want to measure the drawn FPS over a period of time while performing some actions on a device. Is there a way to output and save this FPS measure? E.g. to print the FPS with Dumpsys to Logcat every second?

What I want to achieve is to test if my App is not reacting smooth in some ways and to quanitfy that.

"adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo" only prints an aggregated analysis of frame data across the entire lifetime.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try [GameBench](https://www.gamebench.net), which is very handy.
Just run the app on your device and let your own app runs for a period of time, then you can get the statistics about it.